# How to connect to hosted Team Foundation Service from command line

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have signed up on http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/pricing/tfs-information, and it is working in Eclipse and VS but not working in the command line.

I am receiving an `authenticating error` I don't know the username; I am trying email.

How can I access Team Foundation Service from the command line?

Comment: "can I access tfs.viusalstudio.com from command line ?" Yes.

Comment: I don't know the username, I try email and its password but not success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Windows Command-Line Client**

From the command-line, you should be prompted with a pop up dialog prompting you to authenticate to Team Foundation Service with your Microsoft ID.  You should not need to perform additional authentication.

**Cross-Platform Command-Line Client**

If you are not provided with an authentication dialog, then I suspect you downloaded and installed the Team Explorer Everywhere Command-Line Client when you downloaded the TFS plug-in for Eclipse.  This is the cross-platform command-line client for Team Foundation Server.

The cross-platform command-line client will *not* raise UI at any point, including to prompt for authentication to the service.  Instead, you should set up [alternate credentials](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2012-aug-27/) for use with the TEE CLC.

Note that the TEE CLC is not officially supported under Windows (we recommend using `tf.exe` that is bundled with Visual Studio Team Explorer.)  The command-line client that is included with Visual Studio is more performant.

Comment: thank you for answer,but I have error when I connect the server
`tf workspace -new workspace -collection:https://motaz.visualstudio.com/`

 `An error occurred: The SOAP endpoint https://motaz.visualstudio.com/Services/v1.
0/Registration.asmx could not be contacted.  HTTP status: 404`

Comment: Your URL is not complete, it's missing the collection.  Try `https://motaz.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection` as the URL on the command-line.

Comment: you saved my life, I can live normally now, thank you very much